# WinPCap packet reassembly

Tags: packet-sniffers, winpcap, ip-fragmentation

I am writing an application using WinPCap that will capture packets on the network and allow me to troubleshoot some of our network applications. Everything works fine until the packets are fragmented.

WinPCap appears to be sending me incorrect offsets and fragmentation options for the packets.

Here is the data for each packet.

```
Packet.IpV4.Fragmentation.Offset = 136
Packet.IpV4.Fragmentation.Options = None
Packet.IpV4.Fragmentation._value = 17
Packet.IpV4.Identification = 61876
```

I always get 5 of these packets (I'm sending the same test data every time) with these values. I thought the Offset and Options should change depending on the packet so I could reassemble the payload data correctly.

I'm now at a loss as to how to use WinPCap to get packet data for anything that is fragmented.

Anyone have any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.